# How/where to buy mixed-class tickets for a flight?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, children

I want to buy two business class tickets, and two coach - for the same flights. So far every site I saw allows me to pick tickets in single class only, so I'd have to buy them separately, which causes problems, as not all flights seem to be available in both business and coach.

The reason behind my request is that I want to couch tickets for kids, and two business for me and my wife.

Is there any trick to make purchasing such tickets easier? Or perhaps there is some site that caters to such family needs?

Comment: Your big problem is that a single booking may only contain passengers in the same fare class. You will have to have therefore two different bookings (with different references, ticket numbers etc). There may be ways to do it easily (eg speak to a real travel agent!), but be aware you'll end up with two bookings

Comment: fascinating! Ohz, I would purchase by calling the airline, in that case.

Comment: Hey Gagr, you're quite sure about that?  It's so common for nannies etc to fly in the economy section.  Same deal with business groups - the bosses sit up front and the rest in the back.

Comment: Separate classes will always be separate bookings, one for business class, one for economy class.  Bookings can be tied together so that any flight changes are matched, but they are still two separate PNRs.

Comment: Well, I get that it needs to be separate booking, but I can't see why exactly can't this be "bundled" somehow by ticket selling/searching software. Even if, at the end, I would have 2 "buy" buttons, I would be sure that the flights 100% match, and both (or more) purchases will give me tickets on the same flights.

Comment: The likely reason it is not available is a lack of demand for that functionality.  Evidentally the number of parents who relegate their kids to economy while they travel first class is but a small portion of traveling families.  And the coding necessary to create what would be essentially a parallel booking algorithm isn't a decent ROI.

Comment: How old are your kids?  As has been said you'll need to put them on a separate ticket, and if they are below a certain age that'll cause all sorts of problems due to the being minors and (seemingly) flying alone.  You may need to book one ticket you+kid1 in business and the other wife+kid2 in economy, and then shuffle as to which seats you actually sit in. The exact process will depend on the specific airline, so it's best to start by talking to them.

Comment: Why can't you sit with your kids in economy? This sounds like a horrible thing to do. Is it really that important for you to sit in business class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was explained in the comments:

The way that all the airline booking systems work, it is not possible to have people on different booking (fare) classes on the same ticket. If you have two people on the same flights in the same booking classes, it's fine. If you have two people on the same flights but different booking classes (could be business and economy, or even just flexible vs non-flexible economy), then they *must* be on different tickets and PNRs.

You therefore need to make two different bookings for you, one for the people in one booking class (+cabin), one for the people on the same flight but in the other booking class.

Your best bet in this case is to skip the internet, and talk to (shock horror!) a person. Be that a travel agent, or the airline's booking line, either should work. They will create the two itineraries for you, hold them while you confirm you're happy and double check that everything else is the same, then ticket the two for you. They should also be able to attach notes to indicate the bookings are linked.

Oh, and one thing to be aware of, because you'll have two bookings, if there's a problem with the flight and it gets cancelled, you will almost certainly have to speak with another human. Otherwise, you may find that you and your wife are re-routed one way, your kids another, because the automated re-booking system won't necessarily know to keep the two together because they're on different bookings.

Note that if by "mixed-class tickets" what you means was the more common "one way in economy, return in business" or something like that, then many (but not all) online flight booking systems will be able to sell you the ticket, as will the airline or a travel agent.

Comment: let's say "mixed purchase": meaning some tix are business or first, some tix are economy.  I've never had **the slightest problem** booking a "mixed purchase" from a travel agent, over decades.  It is the norm for business travel with groups (bosses up front, headcount in the back).  For, I suppose you would say, rich people, it's completely the norm.  (Parents up front, au-pair up back, and kids nobody knows or cares, strapped to the wheels, whatever.) So it's a total non-issue with travel agents / is the Normal Situation. With online services - I do not know.

Comment: No idea where this "horror" thing came from, about talking to person. I have nothing against talking to people. The thing is, that I have no idea where "travel agencies" exist, as I always ever bought tickets online. And "talk to airline" looks strange to me, as online booking often sells me tickets that are handled by multiple airlines on different hops.

Comment: If it's all within one alliance, the phone sales team of any of the airlines you fly with should be able to sell you it, they're normally used to handling special cases. Travel Agencies exist all over, though in some bits of the world they're in more obvious places than others. Some you'd need to go there in person, some are happy to work on the phone, occasionally some will work by email - that can be very convenient!